# Como dividir uma string de 3 em 3 letras

Tags: python

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu estou fazendo um programa em python 3 parecido com aqueles tradutores de código binário, base64 etc eu já fiz o que vai transformar as palavras em código agora quero fazer o programa que vai transformar o código em palavras para isso tenho que dividir o código que o usuário escreveu de 3 em 3 letras exemplo G70H74L10M90 Com a separação vai ficar assim G70 H74 L10 M90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc pode tentar importando o modulo `re`.

```
import re

# string de entrada
string = "G70H74L10M90"

# quebra a string, mas inclui strings vazias
lista = re.split("(\S{3})", string)

# remove strings vazias, deixa apenas o que interessa
final = list(filter(None, lista))

print(final)
```